# Display Paragraphs in UITextView without \n

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, line-breaks, paragraph

Is there a convenient way to format a rather long string with paragraphs in it (like below) to have it with `\n` in it so the textView will display the paragraphs as well?

```
blah

blah
```

to `@"blah\n\nblah"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example assuming you have :

- A file named : myfile.txt
- A string variable to hold the file's content, let's name it : content
- A UITextView called :textView

Write whatever you want in your text file and place it wherever you want in your Xcode project (usually import it from within Xcode under "Ressources"), and then somewhere in your code (init method or action) :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path 
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                 error:NULL];

textView.text = content;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your text in a .txt file in your Bundle and load it with

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youTextFile" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"yourRessourceDirectory"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Okay … If I added my txt file just by dragging it to my xcode project in xcode, would the directory be the group of it? For instance: myProject -> Group "Resources" -> myText.txt?

Comment: Depends of how you create the group. If you doesn't need directory you can use pathForResource:ofType: instead of pathForResourcsOfType:inDirectory: